# SetObject forKey Updates All Previous Item

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I'm looking for Update Foods Order Whenever i call a method and the method will save the count of orders and update if the food exist in dictionary
here is my code :

```
-(void) addObjectsToArrayWithFoodName: (NSString *)foodName andPrice:(NSString *)price andCount:(NSString *)count andID:(NSString *)ID{
    [_arrDicFoodDetails removeAllObjects];

    if ([count isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [_dicFood removeObjectForKey:ID];
        return;
    }
    [_arrDicFoodDetails addObject:foodName];
    [_arrDicFoodDetails addObject:price];
    [_arrDicFoodDetails addObject:count];



    [_dicFood setObject:_arrDicFoodDetails forKey:ID];

    }
}
```

But when i use this code somethings happen .
imagine that we add food with id (0) and count (1) its all good .
if we update food (0) and count(2) , again all good .
but if we add food with id (3) and count (1) it will update record of food(0) too new data .

i hope u understand whats going on ... thanks

Comment: Use local array (or local custom object). remove the _arrDicFoodDetails, and use a local array

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same array each time.  Ditch that instance variable `_arrDicFoodDetails` and create a new array each time:

```
-(void) addObjectsToArrayWithFoodName: (NSString *)foodName andPrice:(NSString *)price andCount:(NSString *)count andID:(NSString *)ID{
    if ([count isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [_dicFood removeObjectForKey:ID];
        return;
    }

    _dicFood[ID] = @[ foodName, price, count ];
}
```

This statement is somewhat alarming, however:

```
count isEqualToString:@"0"
```

Numbers aren't strings, so use the correct data type.  Also consider using a custom object, rather than arrays, to group data *and functionality*.